# Guardar un arreglo de productos en un catalogo

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Estoy realizando un backend para una app donde usuarios crean catálogos y añaden productos al catalogo.

Actualmente tengo dos modelos

**productos.model.js**

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const ProductoSchema = new Schema({
   nombre: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   descripcion: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   categoria: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   precio: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
   },
   stock: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0
   },
   img: {
      type: String
   },
   catalogo: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Catalogo'
   }
}, {
   versionKey: false
});

ProductoSchema.method('toJSON', function() {
   const {_id, ...object} = this.toObject();
   object.id = _id;
   return object;
});

module.exports = model('Producto', ProductoSchema);
```

**catalogo.model.js**

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const TiposDePagoSchema = new Schema({
   zelle: {
      type: String
   },
   paypal: {
      type: String
   },
   transferencia: {
      type: String
   },
   pagomovil: {
      type: String
   },
   efectivo: {
      type: Boolean
   }
});

const redesSocialesSchema = new Schema({
   instagram: {
      type: String
   },
   facebook: {
      type: String
   },
   twitter: {
      type: String
   }
});

const CatalogoSchema = new Schema({
   nombre: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   telefono: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   img: {
      type: String
   },
   tiposDePago: [TiposDePagoSchema],
   redesSociales: [redesSocialesSchema],
   usuario: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Usuario'
   },
   productos: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Producto'
   }]
}, {
   versionKey: false
});

CatalogoSchema.method('toJSON', function() {
   const {_id, ...object} = this.toObject();
   object.id = _id;
   return object;
});

module.exports = model('Catalogo', CatalogoSchema);
```

En teoría el catalogo esta relacionándose con los productos, pero cuando hago una petición a la ruta de catalogo que es ejecutada por este controller

**catalogo.controller.js**

```
const { response } = require('express');

const Catalogo = require('../models/catalogo');

const agregarCatalogo = async (req, res = response) => {
   const {nombre, telefono, img, tiposDePago, redesSociales} = req.body;
   try {
      const catalogo = new Catalogo({nombre, telefono, img, tiposDePago, redesSociales});
      catalogo.usuario = req.uid;
      await catalogo.save();
      res.json({
         ok: true,
         catalogo
      });
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({
         ok: false,
         msg: 'Error inesperado.'
      });
   }
}

const obtenerCatalogos = async (req, res = response) => {
   try {
      const catalogos = await Catalogo.find().populate('usuario', 'nombre');
      res.json({
         ok: true,
         catalogos
      });
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({
         ok: false,
         msg: 'Error inesperado.'
      });
   }
}

const obtenerCatalogoPorId = async (req, res = response) => {
   const id = req.params.id;
   try {
      const catalogo = await Catalogo.findById(id).populate('usuario', 'nombre');
      if (!catalogo) {
         return res.status(404).json({
            ok: false,
            msg: 'No existe un catalogo por ese id.'
         });
      }
      res.json({
         ok: true,
         catalogo
      });
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({
         ok: false,
         msg: 'Error inesperado.'
      });
   }
}

const actualizarCatalogo = async (req, res = response) => {
   const id = req.params.id;
   try {
      const catalogo = await Catalogo.findById(id);
      if (!catalogo) {
         return res.status(404).json({
            ok: false,
            msg: 'No existe un catalogo por ese id.'
         });
      }
      const catalogoActualizado = await Catalogo.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, {new: true});
      res.json({
         ok: true,
         catalogoActualizado
      });
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({
         ok: false,
         msg: 'Error inesperado.'
      });
   }
}

const borrarCatalogo = async (req, res = response) => {
   const id = req.params.id;
   try {
      const catalogo = await Catalogo.findById(id);
      if (!catalogo) {
         return res.status(404).json({
            ok: false,
            msg: 'No existe un catalogo por ese id.'
         });
      }
      await Catalogo.findByIdAndDelete(id);
      res.json({
         ok: true,
         msg: 'El catalogo ha sido eliminado.'
      });
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({
         ok: false,
         msg: 'Error inesperado.'
      });
   }
}

module.exports = {
   agregarCatalogo,
   obtenerCatalogos,
   obtenerCatalogoPorId,
   actualizarCatalogo,
   borrarCatalogo
}
```

Se me crea un catalogo pero me deja el array de los productos vacíos. La verdad es que no se como agregarle productos a ese catalogo y que aparezcan en el array de productos que tiene el catalogo.

Adjunto el controller de productos

**productos.controller.js**

```
const { response } = require('express');

const Producto = require('../models/productos');

const agregarProducto = async (req, res = response) => {
   const {nombre, descripcion, categoria, precio, stock, img} = req.body;
   try {
      const nuevoProducto = new Producto({nombre, descripcion, categoria, precio, stock, img});
      await nuevoProducto.save();
      res.json({
         ok: true,
         nuevoProducto
      });
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({
         ok: false,
         msg: 'Error inesperado.'
      });
   }
}

const obtenerProducto = async (req, res = response) => {
   try {
      const productos = await Producto.find({}, 'nombre descripcion categoria precio stock img');
      res.json({
         ok: true,
         productos
      });
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({
         ok: false,
         msg: 'Error inesperado.'
      });
   }
}

const obtenerProductoPorId = async (req, res = response) => {
   const id = req.params.id;
   try {
      const existeProducto = await Producto.findById(id);
      if (!existeProducto) {
         return res.status(404).json({
            ok: false,
            msg: 'No existe un producto por ese id.'
         });
      }
      const producto = await Producto.findById(id);
      res.json({
         ok: true,
         producto
      });
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({
         ok: false,
         msg: 'Error inesperado.'
      });
   }
}

const actualizarProducto = async (req, res = response) => {
   const id = req.params.id;
   try {
      const existeProducto = await Producto.findById(id);
      if (!existeProducto) {
         return res.status(404).json({
            ok: false,
            msg: 'No existe un producto por ese id.'
         });
      }
      const productoActualizado = await Producto.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, {new: true});
      res.json({
         ok: true,
         productoActualizado
      });
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({
         ok: false,
         msg: 'Error inesperado.'
      });
   }
}

const eliminarProducto = async (req, res = response) => {
   const id = req.params.id;
   try {
      const existeProducto = await Producto.findById(id);
      if (!existeProducto) {
         return res.status(404).json({
            ok: false,
            msg: 'No existe un producto por ese id.'
         });
      }
      await Producto.findByIdAndDelete(id);
      res.json({
         ok: true,
         msg: 'Producto eliminado.'
      });
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({
         ok: false,
         msg: 'Error inesperado.'
      });
   }
}


module.exports = {
   agregarProducto,
   obtenerProducto,
   obtenerProductoPorId,
   actualizarProducto,
   eliminarProducto
}
```

Nota final: Lo que estoy buscando es crear un catalogo y a ese catalogo asignarle productos.

El resultado final de lo que quisiera tener en mi catalogo es algo como esto:

```
{
    "nombre": "Tilifonek",
    "telefono": "04245853827",
    "img": "",
    "redesSociales": [
        {
            "instagram": "tilifonekbqto"
        }
    ],
    "tiposDePago": [
        {
            "zelle": "andrespvzla@gmail.com",
            "paypal": "andrespvzla@gmail.com",
            "transferencia": "Cuenta: 01340946350001235147 - CI: 23.903.545"
        }
    ],
    "productos": [
        {
            "nombre": "Laptop MSI",
            "categoria": "Laptops",
            "descripcion": "Es una laptop MSI",
            "precio": 899,99,
            "stock": 10,
            "img": "rutaimg"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "Laptop HP",
            "categoria": "Laptops",
            "descripcion": "Es una laptop HP",
            "precio": 499,99,
            "stock": 15,
            "img": "rutaimg"
        },
    ]
}
```

Voy a adjuntar mi repositorio para que lo verifiquen.

https://github.com/Andrespvzla/backend-catalogo

Comment: Se crea el catálogo con los valores que le indicas: `const catalogo = new Catalogo({nombre, telefono, img, tiposDePago, redesSociales});` Allí no se ve que le asignes ningún producto a tu catálogo. No se van a añadir a menos que se lo indiques explícitamente. Luego está el tema de la actualización: `const catalogoActualizado = await Catalogo.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, {new: true});`, ¿qué pasa si mi objeto `req.body` contiene una lista de productos con 1 sólo producto y el catálogo existente tiene cientos de productos en su lista? Se reemplazará la lista de cientos por la lista de 1!!!

Comment: Otro problema es la referencia circular que tienes. El modelo de productos tiene una referencia a la colección de catálogos. ¿Puede un producto aparecer en más de un catálogo o no? Esa es una decisión de diseño que debes tomar. Además si ya tienes esa referencia en el modelo de productos, ¿porqué añadir la referencia contraria en el modelo de catálogo? Un producto apunta a un catálogo que a su vez apunta a una lista de productos, que tiene entre sus elementos el producto inicial, eso es innecesario y es una pérdida de espacio. Define primero tu lógica antes de intentar hacer las referencias.

Comment: Entiendo, que no le estoy asignando productos al catalogo y esa es la parte que quiero hacer tomando en cuenta el producto.controller.js pero no se como realizarlo.

Ahora bien, la relación que quiero es la siguiente un catalogo que contiene productos, los productos no pueden estar solos sin su respectivo catalogo, y no puede existir un mismo producto en 2 catálogos. Cada catalogo tiene sus productos y son independientes

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

Tu problema está en la forma en la que pretendes hacer una referencia de los documentos de tipo *productos* en los documentos de tipo *catálogos*. Según [tus propias palabras](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/396126/guardar-un-arreglo-de-productos-en-un-catalogo#comment709356_396126):

> Entiendo que no le estoy asignando productos al catálogo y esa es la parte que quiero hacer tomando en cuenta el `producto.controller.js` pero no sé cómo realizarlo. Ahora bien, la relación que quiero es la siguiente: un catálogo que contiene productos, los productos no pueden estar solos sin su respectivo catálogo, y no puede existir un mismo producto en 2 catálogos. Cada catalogo tiene sus productos y son independientes.

Y aunque no quiero decir abiertamente que tu diseño está mal, ya que tu caso de uso está cubierto, lo que si puedo decirte es que tu diseño no es extensible. Si el día de mañana, se desea permitir que un producto pertenezca a diferentes catálogos, entonces tendrías que modificar tu modelo de datos, lo cual implica un gran cambio e impacto en un sistema en producción. La lógica de negocio debe ajustarse también para introducir este *pequeño* cambio.

**SOLUCIÓN**

**Resumen**

Se me ocurren diferentes formas de solucionar el problema, pero eso sería una respuesta muy larga, así que sólo te daré una posible solución al problema actual y luego mostraré una forma (de las muchas existentes) para hacer tu modelo de datos extensible.

**Con el esquema de datos actual**

Como te dije en mi comentario, tienes una referencia circular:

```
//Esquema de Producto
catalogo: {
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Catalogo'
}

// Esquema de Catálogo
productos: [{
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Producto'
}]
```

Tal como tienes tu esquema de datos, una posible solución al problema podría ser la siguiente:

```js
// añadimos un producto al catálogo durante la creación del producto
// si tenemos la id del catálogo, eso implica actualizar el catálogo
const agregarProducto = async (req, res = response) => {
   const {nombre, descripcion, categoria, precio, stock, img, catalogo} = req.body;
   try {
      const nuevoProducto = new Producto({nombre, descripcion, categoria, precio, stock, img, catalogo});
      await nuevoProducto.save();
      // si el producto tiene asociado un catálogo, lo actualizamos
      if(nuevoProducto.catalogo) {
        await Catalogo.addProducts([nuevoProducto._id], nuevoProducto.catalogo);
      }
      res.json({
         ok: true,
         nuevoProducto
      });
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({
         ok: false,
         msg: 'Error inesperado.'
      });
   }
}
```

Obviamente el servicio de Catálogos debe tener un método para añadir productos, el cual podría verse parecido a lo siguiente:

```js
// Servicio de catalogos
const addProducts = async (productos, id) => {
  try {
    const update = { $addToSet: {productos: { $each: productos } } };
    await Catalogo.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update);
    return;
  catch(error) {
    // error handler
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Cuando se actualiza un producto también se necesita una forma de añadir los productos a la lista y cuando se cambia un producto de un catálogo a otro también debemos hacer operaciones de actualización sobre los catálogos implicados, lo que nos lleva a replantear toda la lógica del programa.

***tl;dr***

Al parecer (aunque esto no es más que una suposición, por lo que planteas en tu pregunta), crees que sólo por escribir las referencias, los campos serán *poblados* automáticamente al crearse un documento. Sin embargo esto no es lo que sucede. Cuando se crea un documento basándose en el esquema de datos escrito en Mongoose, los campos a ser llenados son los que le pasamos al constructor, nada más. Mongoose no buscará referencias en la base de datos para llenar otros campos. Las referencias están allí para poder hacer una búsqueda (*lookup*) en la colección adecuada cuando se necesiten los datos a los que apuntan las referencias.

Otro problema que plantea tu esquema de datos es el dilema del [*huevo o la gallina*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_huevo_o_la_gallina). Por ejemplo:

1. Un usuario se registra
2. Crea un catálogo (no hay productos)
3. Crea un producto y lo incorpora al catálogo (previamente creado)

Esa sería la lógica detrás del caso de uso planteado en tu pregunta, pero ¿qué pasa con el siguiente caso de uso?:

1. Un usuario se registra
2. Crea un producto (no hay catálogo aún, ¿se puede o no se puede crear productos sin catálogos previamente creados?)
3. Se crea un catálogo (se le puede agregar el producto creado en 2, implica actualizar el producto para que apunte al catálogo recién creado)

El punto 2 en el caso de uso anterior plantea una decisión de diseño. ¿Permito crear productos si no existe un catálogo para el mismo? ¿Entienden los usuarios realmente el propósito de relación uno a uno entre catálogo y producto? ¿Qué pasa si me equivoco y asigno un producto al catálogo erróneo? ¿Puedo tener más de un catálogo? etc., etc. etc.

El *dilema del huevo y la gallina* viene dado por el hecho de que al crear un catálogo no hay productos para añadir a la lista de productos, entonces me veré tentado a crear primero el producto. Pero resulta que cuando estoy creando el producto, me pide el `id` del catálogo al que va a pertenecer dicho producto, por lo cual vuelvo al principio, ya que no tengo aún un catálogo creado.

La solución a este problema puede ser sencilla, pero necesita un poco de análisis de nuestra situación. Si la idea de un catálogo es presentar los productos presentes en el mismo, pues tiene sentido usar un campo de tipo lista que almacene las referencias (únicas) a un documento de tipo *producto*. Con "únicas", me refiero a que debo garantizar que no existan entradas repetidas en dicha lista. Luego, si un usuario sólo puede tener un catálogo, no hará falta una referencia en el documento de *productos* indicando a qué catálogo pertenece el mismo. Pero si existe la posibilidad de tener más de un catálogo, entonces me veré tentado a asignar esta referencia, la cual al final puede ser un arma de doble filo, ya que puede suceder que un producto sea trasladado de un catálogo a otro, pero por alguna razón no se actualiza la referencia en el documento de dicho producto, o puede darse el caso contrario, en el que se actualiza la referencia del producto, pero el traslado entre catálogos nunca se lleva a cabo. Por lo tanto los datos son inconsistentes. Y a medida que nuestra base de datos aumenta en tamaño y las operaciones aumentan en complejidad, será muy difícil mantener las cosas en orden.

**Eliminando el campo productos en el modelo de catálogo**

Una forma sencilla de evitar el problema de mantener los datos consistentes es eliminar la referencia circular, eliminando la lista de productos del catálogo, al fin y al cabo tu lista no es más que una serie de valores redundantes ya que los mismos pueden obtenerse del campo *catalogo* del documento de *producto*.

Para obtener todos los productos de un catálogo, puedes usar una consulta de [*agregación*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation/) en la cual simplemente vas a agregar los productos que tengan una referencia al catálogo consultado. De esta forma tienes sólo que preocuparte por mantener el producto actualizado y no necesitas preocuparte por actualizar el catálogo por cada cambio en el campo asociado en el producto.

Una consulta de agregación por `id` podría verse así:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Catalogo = require('../models/catalogo');

const obtenerCatalogoPorId = async (req, res = response) => { 
  const idCatalogo = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id); // el _id del catalogo que deseo consultar
  const agregacion = [
    {$match: {_id: idCatalogo}},
    {$lookup:
      {
        from: 'productos', // <- nombre de la colección de productos
        localfield: '_id',
        foreignfield: 'catalogo',
        as: 'productos'
      }
    },
    {$lookup:
      {
        from: 'usuarios', // <- nombre de la colección de usuarios
        localfield: 'usuario',
        foreignfield: '_id',
        as: 'usuario'
      }
    },
    {$unwind: 'usuario'}
  ];
  
  const catalogos = await Catalogo.aggregate(agregacion).exec(); // <- devuelve un Array
  // ...
}
```

Se ve bastante complicado, pero en realidad es muy sencillo. Esta sería una de las formas de mantener los datos consistentes, eliminando la referencia circular ya que si un producto tiene asociado un catálogo único, entonces no hace falta crear la referencia en el documento de catálogo.

Otra forma es realizar una consulta separada, de tal manera que al momento de consultar un catálogo también se consultan los productos asociados a dicho catálogo y se agregan como parte del documento a ser devuelto al cliente:

```js
const obtenerCatalogoPorId = async (req, res = response) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  try {
    const catalogo = await Catalogo.findById(id).populate('usuario', 'nombre');
    if (!catalogo) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        ok: false,
        msg: 'No existe un catalogo por ese id.'
      });
    }
    const productos = await Producto.find({catalogo: id}); // <- consulto los productos del catálogo
    res.json({
      ok: true,
      catalogo,
      productos
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({
      ok: false,
      msg: 'Error inesperado.'
    });
  }
}
```

Claro que eso implica realizar una segunda consulta y enviar los catálogos por separado de los productos. Para un sólo catálogo es sencillo, pero para más de uno podríamos crear una estructura como la siguiente:

```js
[
  {
    catalogo: catalogo,
    productos: productos
  }
]
```

Por ejemplo:

```js
const obtenerCatalogos = async (req, res = response) => {
  try {
    const catalogos = await Catalogo.find().populate('usuario', 'nombre');
    const allProducts = await Promise.all(catalogos.map(async catalogo => {
      const productos = await Producto.find({catalogo: catalogo._id});
      return productos;
    }));
    const results = catalogos.map((catalogo, index) => {
      return {catalogo: catalogo, productos: allProducts[index]}
    });
    res.json({
      ok: true,
      catalogos: results
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({
      ok: false,
      msg: 'Error inesperado.'
    });
  }
}
```

**Mantener la lista de productos y crear los métodos de actualización adecuados**

Otra posible solución, manteniendo la referencia circular, es actualizar la lista de productos cada vez que se crea, actualiza o elimina un producto. Esto plantea un desafío mayor, y es que las transacciones sobre diferentes documentos no son atómicas, por lo tanto si en la cadena de procesos uno falla, la base de datos quedará en un estado inconsistente. MongoDB introdujo las transacciones a partir de la versión 4.0, en bases de datos de réplica (no son bases de datos individuales o *standalone*) y también se añadió soporte a transacciones para los servidores en *clúster fragmentado* (a partir de MongoDB 4.2). Pero si tu base de datos es de desarrollo, seguramente no tengas un servidor de réplica o uno de tipo fragmentado, por lo cual no tendrás disponible las [transacciones](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/index.html#transactions-and-atomicity).

Si nos olvidamos por un momento del problema de atomicidad de las operaciones, podemos tener la siguiente solución al problema:

```js
// añadimos un producto al catálogo durante la creación del producto
// si tenemos la id del catálogo, eso implica actualizar el catálogo
const agregarProducto = async (req, res = response) => {
   const {nombre, descripcion, categoria, precio, stock, img, catalogo} = req.body;
   try {
      const nuevoProducto = new Producto({nombre, descripcion, categoria, precio, stock, img, catalogo});
      await nuevoProducto.save();
      // si el producto tiene asociado un catálogo, lo actualizamos
      if(nuevoProducto.catalogo) {
        await Catalogo.addProducts([nuevoProducto._id], nuevoProducto.catalogo);
      }
      res.json({
         ok: true,
         nuevoProducto
      });
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({
         ok: false,
         msg: 'Error inesperado.'
      });
   }
}
```

En el código anterior, verificamos si al momento de crear un producto, el mismo es asignado a un catálogo. Si el producto es asignado a algún catálogo, debemos actualizar la lista de productos de dicho catálogo. Para ello, nuestro servicio de catálogos debe implementar algún método que nos permita actualizar dicha lista. El método recibe un `Array`, para hacerlo extensible en el caso de que deseemos incorporar más de un producto a la vez.

Un ejemplo del método para actualizar la lista sería el siguiente:

```js
// Servicio de catalogos
const addProducts = async (productos, id) => {
  try {
    const catalogo = await Catalogo.findById(id);
    if(!catalogo) {
      const error = new Error('No se encontró el catálogo solicitado');
      throw error;
    }
    if(!catalogo.productos) { // si el catálogo aún no contiene productos
      catalogo.productos = [];
    }
    catalogo.productos.addToSet(...productos);
    await catalogo.save();
    return;
  catch(error) {
    // error handler
    throw error;
  }
}
```

En este método estamos usando [`addToSet`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoosearray_MongooseArray-addToSet), el cual es un método que nos permite añadir elementos sin repetición a una lista. Primero obtenemos el catálogo a modificar mediante su `id` y luego actualizamos la lista de productos haciendo uso del [operador de propagación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Sintaxis_Spread), para incluir los elementos de la lista de productos recibida.

Como puedes observar, es sencillo implementar un método que actualice la lista de productos en un catálogo, lo mismo puedes hacer para eliminar un producto de un catálogo, por ejemplo, podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```js
// Servicio de catalogos
const removeProducts = async (productos, id) => {
  try {
    const update = { $pullAll: {productos: productos} };
    await Catalogo.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update);
    return;
  catch(error) {
    // error handler
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Se ve mejor haciéndolo en una sola línea, que no en múltiples como el ejemplo donde se modifica el catálogo. Puedes reescribir el método para añadir productos al catálogo para usar [`findByIdAndUpdate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) tal como se muestra a continuación:

```js
// Servicio de catalogos
const addProducts = async (productos, id) => {
  try {
    const update = { $addToSet: {productos: { $each: productos } } };
    await Catalogo.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update);
    return;
  catch(error) {
    // error handler
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Ahora ya tenemos 2 métodos que nos permitirán actualizar (añadir o eliminar) la lista de productos en un catálogo, de tal forma que no creará elementos repetidos dentro de la lista.

Por último, al momento de consultar un catálogo o una lista de catálogos, usando esta solución, simplemente debes llamar al método [`populate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), algo tan simple como:

```js
const obtenerCatalogoPorId = async (req, res = response) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  try {
    const catalogo = await Catalogo.findById(id)
      .populate('usuario', 'nombre') // <- solo el nombre del usuario
      .populate('productos'); // <- todos los campos del producto en cada producto de la lista
    //...
  }
}
```

**Extensibilidad**

Ahora que ya tienes al menos 2 formas de realizar la tarea, hablemos sobre la extensibilidad.

Tal como tienes planteado tu modelo de datos, el mismo no es extensible. Y es que si en algún momento cambian las especificaciones de los mismos, te quedarías con una situación de actualización masiva de los datos.

Otro de los problemas que veo en la forma en que generas los documentos es que no guardas una versión de los mismos. Estás estableciendo el parámetro `versionKey` a `false`, lo cual tiene el siguiente inconveniente:

Supongamos que como administradores del sistema se nos pide actualizar el `_id` de un producto particular de la lista del catálogo. Por lo tanto usamos algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```js
Catalogo.findById(catalogoId, function (err, catalogo) {
  // manejo de errores ..
  
  // obtener el índice del elemento que deseamos actualizar

  catalogo.productos[index] = updatedId;
  catalogo.save(callback);
});
```

Lo cual se convierte en el siguiente comando de actualización:

```
catalogos.update({ _id: catalogId } , { $set: { 'productos.<index>': updatedId }});
```

Esta notación indica que haremos una modificación del elemento de la lista que se encuentra en la posición indicada por `index`, modificando su valor.

¿Qué está mal con esta actualización?

Imagina que durante el proceso de actualización (entre el momento en que obtenemos la posición en la lista y se guardan los cambios), se realiza una actualización en la lista, que modifica la posición del elemento indicado por `index`. Supongamos que el usuario decide eliminar el producto de la lista. El resultado: modificamos el elemento incorrecto, y no nos daremos cuenta, ya que no habrá ningún mensaje de error.

¿Cómo proceder?

La solución está en permitir el sistema de versiones implementado por Mongoose. De esta forma, cada vez que se realice una operación como la planteada sobre un documento que implementa listas (`arrays`), el comando de actualización emitido por Mongoose será:

```
catalogos.update({ _id: catologoId, __v: versionNumber } , { $set: { 'comments.<index>': updatedId }});
```

El número de versión del documento será enviado automáticamente por Mongoose al momento de llamar a `save()`. Si el documento no existiera cuando tratamos de realizar la actualización, podríamos manejar el error sin ningún problema.
catalogo.save(function (err) { console.log(err); // Error: No se encontró el documento. });

Es por este motivo que se aconseja usar siempre el sistema de versiones que provee Mongoose (a partir de la versión 3). Puedes leer un poco más al respecto en [Mongoose v3 part 1 :: Versioning](https://aaronheckmann.blogspot.com/2012/06/mongoose-v3-part-1-versioning.html)

**Eliminar la dependencia estricta del producto con un catálogo**

Si eliminamos el campo `catalogo` existente en el modelo de producto, eliminamos la restricción de que un producto pertenezca a un solo catálogo, en nuestra Base de Datos. Eso nos deja con la posibilidad de implementar esa restricción a nivel de la lógica de aplicación, lo cual nos da más libertad y nos permite extender nuestra aplicación para situaciones en las que se permita que los productos pertenezcan a más de un catálogo.

¿Y cómo aseguramos que un producto sólo pertenezca a un catálogo?

Aquí podemos implementar una serie de soluciones, pero vamos a usar la más básica: una consulta a la DB para saber si el producto que estamos añadiendo a un catálogo ya ha sido agregado a otro o no.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const actualizarCatalogo = async (req, res = response) => {
   const id = req.params.id;
   try {
      const catalogo = await Catalogo.findById(id);
      if (!catalogo) {
         return res.status(404).json({
            ok: false,
            msg: 'No existe un catalogo por ese id.'
         });
      }
      const update = req.body;
      if(req.body.productos) {
        delete update['productos']; // eliminamos el campo productos para reemplazarlo por $addToSet
        const productos = await Promise.all(req.body.productos.filter(async producto => {
          // buscamos algún catálogo que contenga el producto
          const catalogo = await Catalogo.findOne({productos: producto});
          // devolvemos sólo si no se ha encontrado un catálogo
          return !catalogo;
        }));
        // escribimos el objeto de actualización
        update['$addToSet'] = {productos: { $each: productos } };
      }
      // actualizamos el catálogo
      const catalogoActualizado = await Catalogo.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, {new: true});
      res.json({
         ok: true,
         catalogoActualizado
      });
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({
         ok: false,
         msg: 'Error inesperado.'
      });
   }
}
```

Con esta forma de realizar la consulta verificamos que cada producto añadido a un catálogo no existe en ningún otro catálogo (incluyendo el que se está actualizando).

De esta manera, puedes luego consultar la colección de catálogos usando el método `populate()` para traer la información de los productos:

```js
const obtenerCatalogos = async (req, res = response) => {
  try {
    const catalogos = await Catalogo.find()
    .populate('usuario', 'nombre') // populate campo usuario
    .populate('productos'); // populate campo productos
    res.json({
      ok: true,
      catalogos
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({
      ok: false,
      msg: 'Error inesperado.'
    });
  }
}
```

De esta forma, la lógica que restringe la posibilidad de que un producto sólo pertenezca a un catálogo se implementa en tu aplicación, y si se necesita cambiar dicho comportamiento, un simple cambio en la lógica te permitirá usar la misma estructura de datos, ya que no has creado tal restricción en los mismos.

Espero que esto te deje claro el panorama sobre cómo atacar y resolver el problema.